# Call phone number from UIButton

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiapplication

I've searched through all the questions and can't seem to find my answer.

I have the following IBAction.  This is crashing every time you tap on the phone number.  I have gone back to the DB and formatted the phone numbers to 5551235555 instead of (555)-123-5555.

```
- (IBAction)callPhone:(UIButton *)sender{

    Bar *items = self.detailItem;
    NSURL *pn = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", items.barPhone]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:pn];
}

- (void)setCallButton:(UIButton *)callButton{

    Bar *items = self.detailItem;
    [callButton setTitle:items.barPhone
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Any code guidance would be appriciated.

Comment: What is the stack trace? And are you sure that `items.barPhone` is not nil?

Comment: Yea, I checked its showing the number.  It's also working fine to setTitle which I've added above.  However 'pn' is showing nil.  Obviously why its not working, but not sure why it's nil.

Comment: No error message just the (lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bar *items = self.detailItem;` is not initiated, so that is why it is returning nil. Try the following:

```
Bar *items = [[Bar alloc] init];
items = self.detailItem;
```

Or what you should have done is make **`items`** an ivar for this particular class. Then you can initiate `items` once and use it throughout your class.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with items, everything is reading correctly there.  This info is a Segue from the TableView.  There appears to be something wrong with creating 'pn'.  It's nil but `items.barPhone` has the right value.

Comment: **pn** is nil. Try what I described above. If `items.barPhone` wasn't nil, pn wouldn't be nil.

Comment: `items.barPhone` is not nil or it would not set the button Title correctly.  I tried your code, assuming the `Bars` is supposed to be `Bar`.  I get the same break

Comment: Okay, try adding `NSLog(@"Bar Item: %@",self.detailItem);` directly after `Bar *items = self.detailItem;` and see what it prints out in the console.

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  I must have accidently set a Breakpoint at this line.  Removed that and everything is good.  I thought I was losing my mind.